# T-Sql Calculate averages using Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

I have the below table and have constructed a recursive CTE query which calculates the average price of the stock for a particular [item no] and the first receipt and uses that average to calculate the subsequent averages i/e receipt 2, receipt 3 until it ends.

This works great if there is only one set of records for item. e.g item no 2000045 (receipt 1,2,3 etc) . However if I have a table of multiple item no and receiptNo this query wont work. someone suggested I use a cursor to iterate through item numbers but not sure. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AKTest](
[IntakeSellingPrice] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
[IntakeSellingAmount] [decimal](38, 6) NULL,
[Item No_] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Posting Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[PurchaseQty] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
[ReceiptNo] [bigint] NULL,
[InventoryBalance] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
[NewBalance] [decimal](38, 20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[AKTest] ([IntakeSellingPrice], [IntakeSellingAmount], [Item No_], [Posting Date], [PurchaseQty], [ReceiptNo], [InventoryBalance], [NewBalance]) VALUES (CAST(75.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(37500.000000 AS Decimal(38, 6)), N'2000045', CAST(0x0000A81F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(500.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), 1, CAST(0.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(500.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[AKTest] ([IntakeSellingPrice], [IntakeSellingAmount], [Item No_], [Posting Date], [PurchaseQty], [ReceiptNo], [InventoryBalance], [NewBalance]) VALUES (CAST(75.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(163575.000000 AS Decimal(38, 6)), N'2000045', CAST(0x0000A82400000000 AS DateTime), CAST(2181.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), 2, CAST(500.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2681.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[AKTest] ([IntakeSellingPrice], [IntakeSellingAmount], [Item No_], [Posting Date], [PurchaseQty], [ReceiptNo], [InventoryBalance], [NewBalance]) VALUES (CAST(83.33000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(55.555831 AS Decimal(38, 6)), N'2000045', CAST(0x0000A82B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0.66667000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), 3, CAST(2681.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2681.66667000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)))
GO



;WITH   Testcte
AS     (
SELECT A.*, (
                (A.PurchaseQty * A.IntakeSellingPrice) 
                    + 
                    (A.InventoryBalance *  isnull(A2.IntakeSellingPrice, A.IntakeSellingPrice))
                ) /A.NewBalance [RunningAVG]

    from AKTest A
    left join AKTest A2 on A.[Item No_] = A2.[Item No_] and A.ReceiptNo = A2.ReceiptNo +1
    where A.ReceiptNo = 1 -- anchor member
    and A.[Item No_]='2000045'

UNION ALL

SELECT X.* , (
            (X.PurchaseQty * X.IntakeSellingPrice) 
            + 
            (X.InventoryBalance * X1.RunningAVG )
            ) /X.NewBalance [RunningAVG]
    from AKTest X
    join Testcte X1 on X.ReceiptNo = X1.ReceiptNo +1
    and X.[Item No_]='2000045'
   )
SELECT *
FROM   Testcte;
```

for the above query the result is for the average is:

```
75.000000
75.000000
75.002070
```

Comment: It's great that you posted your sample data as DDL+DML, and it's also great that you posted your current query. However you should also post expected result, and for the sake of clarity, please reduce the sample data to include only the columns needed to get that result.

Comment: i have removed the excess columns and data. the cte generates the correct results but only need the above to work when there is addition data.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you need to make it into recursive CTEs etc - but can you not just change the CTE to not just match on ReceiptNo but also ItemNo?

Comment: Thanks, this did work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, all you need to do is remove the hard coded Item number from your cte (`and A.[Item No_]='2000045'` in the anchor part, and `and A.[Item No_]='2000045'` in the recursive part) and simply join the recursive part on item number as well:

```
;WITH   Testcte
AS     (
SELECT A.*, (
                (A.PurchaseQty * A.IntakeSellingPrice) 
                    + 
                    (A.InventoryBalance *  isnull(A2.IntakeSellingPrice, A.IntakeSellingPrice))
                ) /A.NewBalance [RunningAVG]

    from AKTest A
    left join AKTest A2 on A.[Item No_] = A2.[Item No_] and A.ReceiptNo = A2.ReceiptNo +1
    where A.ReceiptNo = 1 -- anchor member
    -- and A.[Item No_]='2000045' -- removed this condition
UNION ALL

SELECT X.* , (
            (X.PurchaseQty * X.IntakeSellingPrice) 
            + 
            (X.InventoryBalance * X1.RunningAVG )
            ) /X.NewBalance [RunningAVG]
    from AKTest X
    join Testcte X1 on X.ReceiptNo = X1.ReceiptNo +1
    and X.[Item No_] = X1.[Item No_] -- this is instead of the next line (that's commeneted out)
    -- and X.[Item No_]='2000045' -- removed this as well
   )
```